# ROS : Subscribe to topic in different namespace

Tags: ros

I just started to use ROS tonight.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

This is what I have already done :

- publish and subscribe to topic_b.
- publish to ns1/topic_a (I checked with `rostopic echo /ns1/topic_a`)
- publish to ns2/topic_a (I checked with `rostopic echo /ns2/topic_a`)
- subscribe to ns2/topic_a (`ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topic_a", 1000, callback);`)

What I don't know how to do :

- subscribe to ns1/topic_a from node_b.

After reading the tutorial, I tried this :

1/ In node_b.cpp, I subscribed to /topic_a_temp.

2/ In the launch file, inside the node_b tags, I added `<remap from="topic_a_temp" to="ns1/topic_a">`

But it doesn't work.

It may be very basic since I'm a beginner but I don't know how to read the ns1 topic from the ns2 node.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: How about `<remap from="topic_a_temp" to="/ns1/topic_a">`? Note the added forward slash which tells ROS to look up the name as it's written, not relative to whatever namespace the node is launching in. Also, using `rosnode info` or other introspection tools to check which topics nodes are actually subscribing can be helpful for resolving such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a slash to your topic remap instruction:
`<remap from="topic_a_temp" to="/ns1/topic_a">`

ROS will then look up the name globally as it's written, not relative to the namespace the node is launching in. For more, see [how names are resolved in ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Names#Resolving).

[`rosnode info`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode#rosnode_info) or other introspection tools to check which topics nodes are actually subscribing can be helpful for resolving such problems